# Can Wolkenkit be used as just a server or with graphQL?

Tags: domain-driven-design, graphql, cqrs, event-sourcing, wolkenkit

I really like the [Wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit) server but when I looked at the client library it seemed a bit too opinionated and I might be using graphQL -- which I think will work well to wrangle all the read models. In that case, can I just use the server with http? What would be involved with that?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm interested in combining the two technologies. I have an Apollo client working with a node server, but I'd like all the benefits of CQRS that come with wolkenkit.

Comment: @Erick no, sadly we are too limited by our legacy data composition to use wolkenkit. Have you pushed forward with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can access [wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit) using HTTP or web sockets directly, without the need to use the JavaScript client SDK. All the client SDK does is wrapping the HTTP respective web socket calls in a convenience API.

The server is built upon [tailwind](https://github.com/thenativeweb/tailwind), which is a base module for applications built with CQRS in mind. The best place to start is to have a look at the [HTTP server API](https://github.com/thenativeweb/tailwind/tree/74c6cc4fd0892df50871e4817f9c93503cdbb548/lib/wires/api/http) of tailwind, which is used by wolkenkit. There, one could also add a GraphQL endpoint.

*Please note that I am one of the developers of wolkenkit, so please take my answer with a grain of salt.*